# Can we invoke a method in spring in case the application start fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have situation where I need to perform certain tasks in case my springboot applications fails to start. Basically I want to release various resources. I tried using @PreDestroy annotation but it did not work as application was not started yet. Is there any way out by which we can perform few actions in case springboot application fails to start

Answer (score 0):

Spring app heavily using threadpool context when start the program , so when the main program fail spring can not manage the standard beans related to spring. you can only start new thread using  implements Runnable in main class and no access to spring resources as well , just simple getclassloader().getresourceasstream is available there .

However you can write independence java Agent using -javaagent to do some operation on release resource ,see `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;`